# How to prevent Hudson from entering shutdown mode automatically or when idle?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, shutdown, python-idle

After several months of successful and unadulterated continuous integration, my Hudson instance, running on Mac OSX 10.7.4 Lion, decides it wants to enter shutdown mode after every 20-30 minutes of inactivity.

For those of you familiar with shutdown mode, the instance of course doesn't shutdown, but has the undesirable effect (in this case) of stopping new jobs from starting.

I know I haven't changed any settings, so it makes me think the problem was slowly growing and keeps triggering shutdown mode.

I know there is plenty of storage space on the machine with 400+ GB to go so I'm wondering what else would trigger shutdown mode without actually using the Hudson web portal to manually do it.

As mentioned before, the problem also seems to be tied to inactivity. I tried creating a quick fix, which is a build job that does nothing every 5 minutes. It appeared to work at first, but after long periods of inactivity I will find it back in shutdown mode.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: What platform is the master running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: disable the thinBackup plugin

...

I figured this out by taking a look at the Hudson logs at `http://localhost:8080/log/all`

thinBackup was running every time the Hudson instance went into shutdown mode.

The fact that shutdown mode was occurring at periods of inactivity is also consistent with the behavior of thinBackup.

I then disabled the plug-in and Hudson no longer enters shutdown mode. What's odd is that thinBackup had been installed for some time before this problem starting occurring. I am seeking out a solution from thinBackup to re-enable the plugin without the negative effects and will update here if I get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/370806/), the thinBackup plugin puts Hudson into shutdown mode on purpose to do the backup activity. It is supposed to automatically come out of shutdown mode once it is done.

I saw this with some jobs that seemed to stall and never finish overnight, so Hudson never came out of shutdown mode because thinBackup must have been waiting on the jobs to finish.